# manipulating a string to create directories in unix

Tags: unix, sed, mkdir

I want to take a word as input and creating consecutive directories using the letters of this word in unix shell. I tried sed, awk and fold commands but did not obtaiın any useful result. Any advice?

For example: If input is `hello`, it should create `h/e/l/l/o` directories as one inside another. In other words, `h` will be the top directory and `o` will be the deepest subdirectory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick in any Bourne compatible shell:

```
$ mkdir -p $(echo foobar | sed 's:\(.\):\1/:g')
$ find f
f
f/o
f/o/o
f/o/o/b
f/o/o/b/a
f/o/o/b/a/r
```

Note that `\1` is a *backreference* to the text matched by the first pair of `\(...\)`. Note also that the expansion result is `mkdir -p f/o/o/b/a/r/` -- but `mkdir` ignores the trailing slash to our advantage.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir -p $(echo $1 | sed 's/[0-9a-zA-Z]/\0\//g')
```

EDIT: I suppose some explanation is in order:

1. `mkdir -p` to make a directory tree
2. the directory in question is made from the input, with a transformation
3. the transformation is that any letter or number is turned into itself, followed by a `/` character

Comment: If you want to deal with any characters, `mkdir -p "$(echo "$1" | sed 's/./\0\//g')"`.  Additional quotes to deal with space characters, and an 'any character' match.

Comment: when i tried this, i got all the directories which are equal to 0.

Comment: This doesn't work. What's `\0` supposed to be? It's a literal 0 on FreeBSD and the POSIX Standard renders it undefined behavior.