# Separating characters of a string, bash shell

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to write a script that takes one string argument, divides the string into characters and uses the characters to create directory.

Ex: "./addUser asd" should create a directory named "a" inside the directory that the script is located, it also has to create a directory named "s" as a child directory of "a". Similarly, a directory named "d" has to be created inside the directory "s".

I'm stuck, can you please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [manupulating a string to create directories in unix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244046/manupulating-a-string-to-create-directories-in-unix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution with `mkdir -p`:

```
echo asd | sed 's:.:&/:g' | xargs -n1 -I % mkdir -p "%"
```

or as usual eliminating the useless echo :) and the script format

```
#/bin/bash
<<< "$1" sed 's:.:&/:g' | xargs -n1 -I % mkdir -p "%"
```

this can be used as

```
< filename sed 's:.:&/:g' | xargs -n1 -I % mkdir -p "%"
```

the names are in the file `filename`

or

```
mkdir -p $(echo asd | sed 's:.:&/:g')
```

or

```
mkdir -p $(sed 's:.:&/:g' <<< "asd")
```

as usually, spaces and some special chars could make troubles...

Comment: Thank you,this works fine.
But I also have another similar problem. Now I have to create a text  file in the directory, say, "d". The child directory. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that comes to mind is use a regex to insert `/` between each pair or characters with `mkdir -p`, like:

```
mkdir -p $(echo abc | perl -pi -e 's!.(?=.)!$&/!g')
```

or with `sed`:

```
mkdir -p $(echo abc | sed -e 's!.!&/!g')
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/7579016/2313067, you can use something like

```
x=$1
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#x} ]; do mkdir ${x:$i:1}; cd ${x:$i:1};  i=$((i+1));done
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered something similar to this a few days ago:

[manupulating a string to create directories in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244046/manupulating-a-string-to-create-directories-in-unix/16244078#16244078)

It boils down to

```
mkdir -p $(echo $1 | sed 's/[0-9a-zA-Z]/\0\//g')
```

or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop on your input.

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT="$1"
while read -n 1 CHAR
    mkdir "$CHAR"
    cd "$CHAR"
done <<<"$INPUT"
```